# ChartJS: Full Date for xAxis Labels?

Tags: chart.js

I was been working on a timescale line chart, and noticed that when the all the data points are close enough together, the xAxis labels automatically convert to just time. I have tried different xAxis time units with no success.

Here is a simply codepen example in which the xAxis labels are by hour. If you change a moment to be March instead of April, the xAxis labels are by date.
Is there a way to force the xAxis labels to always be date AND time?

```
xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        parser: timeFormat,
                        // unit: 'day',
                        // unit: 'hour',
                        tooltipFormat: 'll HH:mm'
                    },
```

https://codepen.io/ccwakes/pen/abvzewW

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use property `time.displayFormats` according to [Display Formats](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats) from Chart.js documentation. See [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) for the allowable format strings.

```
time: {
  unit: 'hour',
  displayFormats: {
    hour: 'MMM DD HH:mm'
  },
  tooltipFormat: 'MMM DD HH:mm'
}
```

Please have a look at your amended code below.

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      borderColor: 'red',
      fill: false,
      data: [
        { x: '2020-04-10 13:00', y: 60 }, 
        { x: '2020-04-12 06:00', y: 100 }, 
        { x: '2020-04-12 13:00', y: 5 }
      ],
    }, {
      label: 'Dataset 2',
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      borderColor: 'blue',
      fill: false,
      data: [
        { x: '2020-04-10 13:00', y: 45 }, 
        { x: '2020-04-11 13:00', y: 65 }, 
        { x: '2020-04-12 06:00', y: 80 }, 
        { x: '2020-04-12 13:00', y: 65 }
      ]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    title: {
      text: 'Time Scale'
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'hour',
          displayFormats: {
            hour: 'MMM DD HH:mm'
          },
          tooltipFormat: 'MMM DD HH:mm'
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Date'
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        display: true,
        scaleLabel: {
          display: true,
          labelString: 'Value'
        }
      }]
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: I had tried displayFormats, but must have applied it at the wrong level. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ccwakes: Glad I could help. Please mark the answer as accepted if you think it was the solution to your question (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251399/2358409).